# How to bind a folder with idmap on ZFS with systemd-nspawn

Tags: systemd, zfs, container

It seems that as of Ubuntu 23.10, ZFS now supports idmapping. I wanted to use this to bind mount a ZFS mount /zpool/secure to an nspawn container with root /zpool/kiba, so that the bound mount would be /secure on the container.

Here's the config line.

```
[Files]
BindReadOnly=/zpool/secure:/secure:rootidmap
```

However, when started with machinectl start, the following error occurs.

```
 systemd-nspawn[92969]: Failed to map ids for bind mount /zpool/kiba/secure: Invalid argument
```

What am I missing? What is the argument that's invalid?